# How to convert a photo to pdf every time you click

Tags: android, camera, itext

I'm working on an app where you access and create a folder immediately after clicking get access to the camera and after a bit of photo shots, saving it in this latest in pdf. But I do not know how to turn a jpg to pdf.
I read something about iText but I do not know how to implement it

```
public class CameraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    protected static final String TAG = null;

    /* VARIABILI PRIVATE */
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private boolean mPreviewRunning;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT); //aggiungo il traslucido
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  //no barra titolo
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   //full screen

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton buttonPicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface_button);
        buttonPicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();  //recupero l'holder della surfaceview
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);   //faccio la bind alla nostra activity
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);    //tipo di surface, suggerito nei tutorial ufficiali
    }

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //riparte la preview della camera

                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                if (pictureFile == null){
                    Throwable e = null;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
                        e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                mCamera.startPreview();
            }

        };

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if (mPreviewRunning)
            mCamera.stopPreview();

        //setto le preferenze
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();  //prendo le preferenze della camera
        p.setPreviewSize(arg2, arg3);
        ArrayList<Size> list = (ArrayList<Size>) p.getSupportedPictureSizes();  //recuepro le risoluzioni supportate dalla camera
        int picture_width = list.get(list.size()-1).width;
        int picture_height = list.get(list.size()-1).height;
        p.setPictureSize(picture_width, picture_height);    //setto la camera alla risoluzione pi bassa
        p.setJpegQuality(80);   // qualitˆ compressione JPEG

        // salvo le pref
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            //lancio la preview
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //gestione errore
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = false;
        mCamera.release();

    }


    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    final Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    final  File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        String direct = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES ),direct );
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
             mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }  else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

Give me a hand thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web server doing the conversion,
[mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/) [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)